# Insert data at a particular time automatically using Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I want to insert data into `TrackHabit` model from `DailyHabit` model at a particular time automatically.

The `DailyHabit` model:

```
class DailyHabit(models.Model):
    Habit = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The `TrackHabit` model:

```
class TrackHabit(models.Model):
    Hid = models.ForeignKey(DailyHabit, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    done = models.BooleanField(null=True, default=False)
    done_Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

Actually I want that everyday *Habits* from `DailyHabit` will be added to `TrackHabit` to be able to check whether it is done or not.

Comment: You can look into celery and solar events for this....

Comment: I th'nk celery could be an overkill for your situation, just use schedule.